# Selecting digital componentry in bulk

Tags: serial, components, robotics, camera, ttl

There are **a ton** of electronics retailers and suppliers on the internet, all selling components at (essentially) retail prices. But when big companies need to use digital components (batteries, cameras, motors, etc.) in their products, they certainly aren't going to, say, [Adafruit](http://www.adafruit.com/product/397) and paying $40 per TTL serial camera.

I have a hobby project (involving swarm robotics) that will require me to build hundreds of little tiny independent electronic devices. Each device will be its own "SoC" (system on a chip) and will be complete with its own power source and TTL serial camera. I'm wondering what big electronics manufacturers do when they are designing some new product to sell in stores: where do they go for bulk rate componentry?

As a simple example: when Tyco makes a new RC helicopter toy to sell, I'm sure they don't buy the individual parts from online retailers like JAMECO and pay retail prices. So what do they do? Where do they go? What kinds of "bulk deals" are available to them?

Comment: Other than the distributors such as DigiKey, Mouser, Newark, etc.?

Comment: For smaller quantities (tens of thousands $), use distributors like Arrow or Distrelec. For larger quantities, contact manufacturers directly.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about purchasing.

Comment: @venny, I usually have no problem getting a manufacturer to deal with me directly even for a few hundred dollars worth of parts. Obviously it depends a lot on how big the the manufacturer is and how big a company the customer is working for. But I would place the bar a lot lower than 10's of thousands of dollars before at least looking into what the direct pricing might be.

Comment: I disagree that purchasing isn't part of electrical engineering. In fact it's often the most difficult part.

Comment: I agree with @JeannePindar, this is a critical phase of development of electronic products, and is often overlooked by noobs. This kind of thinking process needs to be answered properly, and not shunned from the EE.SE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience, distributors are prefered for small to medium production quantities. The main reasons for this would be:

- No lead time. Distributors stock components and can deliver them in a day. When buying directly form the manufacturer, lead times of 14-weeks are not unusual and can get much longer for more obscure parts.
- Safety. If you want to buy cheap components from China, you have to worry about counterfeiting. This involves having extensive testing procedure, involving x-ray scans and thorough functional tests.
- Minimum order quantity (MOQ). Manufacturers normaly sell components in quantities of 2500-4000.

You would go directly to the manufacturer if:

- You need a part that's under an NDA and is not sold via normal distribution channels.
- You need a special service as a part of your purchase (e.g. factory programming of chips, custom marking etc).
- The lead time is short and the price is better.

Also worth mentioning is the fact that Big Three (Digikey, Mouser, Farnell/E14) will not alsways be the cheapest option. There are a lot of smaller distributors that offer the same services (and more) at better prices.

EDIT: Adding some info on counterfeiting.

Counterfeit components can be placed in the following categories:

- Completely fake and non-functional parts. You basically get an IC package and nothing inside. You can often use x-ray to check this.
- Night shift. Basically the factory runs an extra shift and makes components for the grey market. They may skip testing to save time and costs.
- Semi-"Functional" parts that pretend to be original. See this [FTDI example](http://zeptobars.ru/en/read/FTDI-FT232RL-real-vs-fake-supereal).
- Recovered parts. These have been desoldered from scrap boards, cleaned up and repackaged.

Comment: Thanks @Armandas - can you elaborate more on "counterfeiting"? I'm shocked this is even an issue, and you make it sound like its a very common one! What are "counterfeit" components? Are they just illegal knockoffs of components that are patented by someone else? Are they even functional?!? Thanks again!

Comment: @smeeb post edited.

Answer (score 1):

You might try a slightly different tack. Make do with distributers, but do 'comparison shopping'.

Creating one Bill of Material (BoM) is quite a lot of work. Finding the right thirty or forty components can take a day or two. I tend to do most of this at a favourite distributer who I have already confirmed carries the key components. This first pass creates an order or 'basket' with all of the manufacturers part numbers, and distributers part numbers.

Even armed with this initial BoM, generating an order for a second distributor can still be quite time consuming. For example, some of the parts might be unique to a distributer ("own brand" parts, like a supermarket), or from different manufacturers, or different families from the same manufacturer. I do this second BoM when I am concerned about cost or part availability.

There are services which do some of the work, and can help to create a basket for each of multiple distributers. Those baskets give the opportunity to compare part costs more easily between those distributers.

For example [Sandsquid](https://www.sandsquid.com/) will take one BoM, and help to create a BoM specific to each of several different distributers (seven I think). They claim to optimise the order, by choosing the lowest cost alternative. They have some demo examples. You don't need to sign-up to see how they work.

It is quite a lot of work to create a BoM for more than a couple of distributers, so this seems like a useful service.

So, for modest quantities of parts, they will take some of the hassle out of searching through each distributer, and let you compare prices for similar parts for each of those distributers. This might save some cost, and also identify the availability of alternative parts.

Comment: Thanks @gbulmer - I know that BoM stands for "Bill of Materials" but I'm not following a lot of what you are talking about here. When you say "*For example Sandsquid will take one BoM, and create one specific BoM/order for each of several distributers. They claim to optimise the order.*", can you give me a concrete example? It might help me understand exactly what you're talking about. Thanks again!

Comment: @smeeb I think what he's trying to say is if you have a parts list all from Farnell (for example) you feed that into this Sandsquid website and they will search all their known distributors for the same part numbers (manufacturer part numbers) and they will generate for example 3 new BoM for you, one for each of the three suppliers who give the best deals. One BoM might only have 5 items on it, but those 5 items are the cheapest from that particular supplier. The other BoM may have a range of remaining parts etc. With those BoM you can go and order the parts :) or at least record options.

Answer (score 1):

Hundreds of pieces is a very small quantity- you'll be dealing with distributors such as Element 14/Newark, Avnet, Digikey, Mouser etc. in North America. Maybe Farnell and others in Europe. Even up to reels of components at a time (a couple thousand to 10,000 parts in a reel), they're not that bad. Prices will probably be several times what a volume manufacturer would pay, but you're paying them to hold stock, to get shipping from a single source and also to guarantee that the supply chain has some integrity (that the parts you buy are not counterfeit, didn't fall off a truck, are not 'seconds' etc.)

At higher quantities you may find you (or your contract assembler) dealing with manufacturers' agents or the manufacturers themselves, but still some distributors. You'll probably be waiting some weeks (8 weeks is common) for the parts to ship. The prices are more likely to be negotiated (perhaps several parts from a single manufactuer will be designed in for a package deal) and might cover a 1-year contract for tens or hundreds of thousands of dollars or more with a single manufacturer. Sales agents will buy you (or your overworked purchasing gal/guy) a decent lunch, trade industry scuttlebutt and the sun will shine a little brighter on you.